# Can't access array in nested immutable object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reactjs

Do that

```
render() {
        var elems = this.props.items.course_list;
        console.log(elems);
        return (
          <div>

          </div>
        )
      }
```

Result:

[image]

Try access to course_list by this:

```
render() {
        var elems = this.props.items.course_list;
        console.log(elems.course_list;);
        return (
          <div>

          </div>
        )
      }
```

Get undefined.

Have object course_list that include array course_list, I can't access to this array

This screen for

var elems = this.props.items;
        console.log(elems);

[image]

Comment: The `;` within the `console.log()` is not valid, is it a typo?

Comment: yes, typo...... but not imoprtant it not working

Comment: could  you try elems['course_list']

Comment: @KamuranSönecek Cannot read property 'course_list' of undefined

Comment: `elems` is already `course_list` in your code.

Comment: could you use this defination : var elems = Object.assign({},this.props.items);

Comment: To access `course_list` from `elems`, it should be declared as `elems = this.props.items`

Comment: @MelanciaUK OBJ course_list have an array inside with name course_list

Comment: Did you try to access `this.props.items.course_list[0]`? What's the result? As this is only a small fragment without any information of what the actual structure of the data should be, it's kind of hard to guess?

Comment: You should then make this clear in your question.

Comment: @Seth Object {} empty

Comment: `course_list` as it's represented here is an `Array[3]`, not an `object` (on the way you're thinking). You can see it yourself from your `console.log()` attached. Based on that, you need to pass an index to the `Array` to return whatever is there.

Comment: Just like @Seth suggested.

Comment: @MelanciaUK Can you show it in full code? not clearly understand what to do

Comment: It's not really about what to do, but about you showing us the structure of this data and understanding some basic principles. There's no proper answer to give here.

Comment: @MelanciaUK but how to show that array ??? What information do you need?

Comment: this.props.items.course_list[0] - when I do this I get empty object

Comment: @ЕгорКротенко can you share the output that you get with console.log(this.props.items)

Comment: The problem is that your code fragment is incomplete. With the information your have supplied `this.props.items.course_list[0]` or, assuming that your console command actually generates that output, `this.props.items.course_list.course_list[0]` should enable you to read the data. If it does not, my assumption right now would be that the output you're showing is generated in a different line. To verify this you could add something like `console.log("Test")` in order to check if that function is actually called.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri updated, last screen

Comment: @Seth update post, please see last screen

Comment: can you access `console.log(elems.count)`

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri no Cannot read property 'count' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to convert the immutable object to a javascript object ot access the inner elements. In that case use `getIn()`. I hope it helps

```
var mystore = state.getIn(['incomeProfileList'])['course_list']; 
var copy = Object.assign({}, mystore); 
console.log(copy.course_list);
```

Comment: import Immutable from 'immutable'

Comment: `const mapStateToProps = function(state) {
  var mystore = state.toArray();
//  console.log(mystore[6]);
  return {
     items: mystore[6]
        };

}
`this is how I get data

Comment: I have seen this, I am just thinking. maybe you can try `state.toJS()` and then see how you return item

Comment: what console.log must be to state?

Comment: so I said try var mystore = state.toJS() and then; try to get item from mystore. console.log(mystore) and share me the result.

Comment: console.log(mystore.incomeProfileList.course_list.course_list); - returns Cannot read property 'course_list' of undefined console.log(mystore.incomeProfileList.course_list); - returns first screen

Comment: could you share the output of mystore only

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134075/discussion-between-shubham-khatri-and--).